# How to make a wired serial touchpad work in 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, mouse, touchpad

I have a Cirque serial touchpad that I would like to use, 
even though the usb mouse works fine.

Checked software center, it shows these are installed:
X.Org Mouse input driver,
X.Org VM mouse driver,
Synaptics touchpad driver, 
Simple Directmedia Layer,
X11 utilities.

I powered down, unplugged the usb mouse, plugged in the serial touchpad and rebooted,
the touchpad does not respond. 
On the Windows computer the regular mouse driver ran the touchpad, 
no special driver was required.

This is not critical but I like the touchpad and a new usb pad costs $40 or $50!
Have not found a question that covers this situation. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the output from: **`dmesg | grep Touch`** ?

Comment: (Please excuse rank amateur!) I typed that into the terminal, hit enter, got another prompt. In other words, no output?

Comment: Verify with **`dmesg`** (look for 'Touch' in output); and check case you type for **Touch**. Also, try again at least 4 minutes after startup.

Comment: Tried it again, have been on for more than an hour, still nothing.

Comment: What is the USB ID for this device? *eg. run command **`lsusb`** with and without device attached, and report what it shows that is different.*

Comment: lsusb returns same data with touchpad attached or not:    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1ea7:0003  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
I suppose that means the touchpad is not seen by ubuntu?

Comment: **Check the cable ..** This might be something other than software.

Comment: Touchpad works fine when I boot up WinXP (did I mention it's dual boot?)